# Labelling on each candle high with value from other column

Tags: plotly-dash, candlestick-chart

I would like to add value from column `perDel`.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(r'..\CandlesPlotPython\APOLLOALLN.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Checklist(
        id='toggle-rangeslider',
        options=[{'label': 'Include Rangeslider', 
                  'value': 'slider'}],
        value=['slider']
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"), 
    [Input("toggle-rangeslider", "value")])
def display_candlestick(value):
    fig = go.Figure(go.Candlestick(
        x=df['Date'],
        open=df['Open Price'],
        high=df['High Price'],
        low=df['Low Price'],
        close=df['Close Price'],
        text=df['perDel']
        
    ))
    
    
    
    
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_rangeslider_visible='slider' in value,
        annotations=[dict(
        x=df['Date'], y=df['High Price'], xref='x', yref='paper',
        showarrow=False, xanchor='left', text=df['perDel'].astype(str))]
        
    )

    return fig

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Error -

> ValueError:
> Invalid value of type 'pandas.core.series.Series' received for the 'text' property of layout.annotation
> Received value: 0       52.5 1      35.54 2      42.56 3      39.88 4      49.67
> ...   246     59.7 247    47.73 248     59.1 249    55.53 250    42.03 Name: perDel, Length: 251, dtype: object
>
> ```
> The 'text' property is a string and must be specified as:
>   - A string
>   - A number that will be converted to a string
> ```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error is saying the problem is that you're setting a pandas `Series` as the value of the `text` property of the `Candlestick` component.

Either pass a number or a string.

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to show using the text property, but you could convert the `df['perDel']` data to a string and pass that to `text`:

```
text=",".join(df["perDel"].astype(str).values)
```

The above would show all numbers in the `perDel` `Series` separated by comma's.